# can i use panel without a frame in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

there are some people? 
i have some question about wxpython ,
can i use panel without a frame?

Comment: Could you state what you're trying to do? It's possible to make a frame such that only the panel will be visible.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is "no". The panel is not a TopLevelWindow. Top level windows are Frames and Windows. Panels typically go in Frames, although you can nest panels in panels or frames. Telling us what to do, as Ryan suggested, would be the best way to get a good answer though.

Answer (score 4):

In the wxpython scheme of things a process creates windows/frames. You can make the decorations (i.e. titlebar and resize/close buttons) hidden such that it looks like a [splash screen](http://wiki.wxpython.org/SplashScreen). But this makes is difficult for the user to easily close the program.